# Distribution of directions of Gaussian primes

Tags: number-theory

I have been wondering about the distribution in the complex plane of Gaussian primes -- essentially those numbers $a + i b$ where $a, b$ are integers and $a^2+b^2$ is a prime number [I know there is another sort but confined on the real line]. Examples are $5+2i$ or $4+i$ (signums are irrelevant of course).

My initial query was about the distribution of phases, i.e. arguments (say $\arctan b/a$), which seems to be uniform -- though one would need some clearcut definition of ``uniform'' if one wants to check, say, Weyl's criterion here.

Another reasonable conjecture is that there exists such Gaussian primes for any given $a$ (resp. $b$). Perhaps even infinitely many? This latter conjectures includes existing conjectures, like whether there exists infinitely many primes succeeding squares, e.g. $p= a^2+1$.

I have looked around and found a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977345/distribution-of-gaussian-primes) but it does really answer mine. The last conjecture appears also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351967/finding-gaussian-primes-along-lines-in-mathbb-zi) and is a special case of [Schintzel's H hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel's_hypothesis_H).

This distribution has some inherent beauty if nothing else:[image: here are the 1000 first ones with $0<b<a$)]

Comment: The existence of infinite primes of the form $n^2+1$ is a long-standing conjecture (on the other hand, Iwaniec and Friedlander proved that there are infinite primes of the form $a^2+b^4$), but the distribution of the arguments should be simpler to deal with through Chebotarev-like results. Interesting question.

Comment: Relevant (Erdos-Hall): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X9800329X/pdf?md5=65e690020aca4d77204273aceef41233&pid=1-s2.0-S0012365X9800329X-main.pdf

Comment: Somewhat related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_moat

Comment: Nice other problem, could be related indeed!